# jQuery clone() method within jQuery TABS shows clone fields on other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery tabs with below code:

```
<ul class="tabNavigation" id="tabs">    
    <li><a href="#AAA">AA</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#BBB">BBB</a></li>    
</ul>  

<div id="AAA">    
    <cfinclude template="AAA.cfm">
</div>  

<div id="BBB">    
               <cfinclude template="BBB.cfm">
</div>
```

Now, on BBB.cfm file, I am cloning a row of the table along with the form fields within the row using following code:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('input#BtnAddSystem').click(
      function($e) {
        $e.preventDefault();
        $('tr#UCrow_1').clone(true).removeAttr('id').appendTo('tbody');
      }
    );

  }
);
```

which works well. The problem is the cloned form fields are also shown up on the "AAA" tabs. so it endup in displaying the cloned form fields on both the tabs.

Can anyone please help me to get it resolved? Any help on this will be much appriciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have an element's ID, there is no reason to also select it by tag name.

Comment: u have confused me, wat tables and rows, i dnt see anything about tables and rows, and ur selectors dont match ur html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the `.appendTo('tbody');` bit that's getting you - this'll append a copy of your row to *every tbody on the page.*  Presumably there's a table in the AAA page too, so it'll have the row appended to it as well.

You'll want to limit it to only select the table you actually want to select.  Something like `.appendTo('#BBB tbody');` should do the trick.  Or better yet, if the tbody has it's own ID, use that: `.appendTo('#clone-dst');`

Hope this helps!

Comment: .appendTo('#BBB tbody'); Worked well! Thank You for your quick response :) I really appriciate it. Thanks Again !!!